# CSV to SQL database displays `?` instead of ü

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, csv

I got a function which makes a SQL database from a CSV file. But when it reads a character with umlaut, it displays a question mark in my SQL table. How can I fix this? This is my code:

```
private static System.Data.DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path, string tablenaam)
{
    System.Data.DataTable csvData = new System.Data.DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }
            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                }
                csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(csvData,tablenaam);
    return csvData;
}
```

Comment: check if your character encodings and localization is set correctly for database, table, column etc.

Comment: Also, don't swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might trick for you

```
TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path, Encoding.GetEncoding(utf-8))
```

The character encoding to use if encoding is not determined from file. Default is UTF8. Thus you need to change the code according to your requirements. Here is the list of [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I got `the name 'utf' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")) solved it, thanks a lot